# Why does Ubuntu logout when I delete something?

Tags: login, delete, restart, logout

I recently realised that after restarting my laptop, I get signed in automatically. But as soon as I delete a column on a spreadsheet or some text on a file, I get signed out and have to log in again. Why does this happen? Is it a safety feature to protect my data?

Comment: You should start by changing the auto login as it isn't recommended, at all.

Comment: @ChanganAuto where does it say that? I use it on 20.04 and 20.10 without issue and I use spreadsheets a lot every day. It's certainly an odd issue but I see no evidence in your comment to support your claim that auto login is the culprit.

Comment: Everywhere in literature, everywhere in the "best practices" book, anyone knows that... Even Windows now make it a lot hardare than Ubuntu to enable it. Just don't use it, period. But yes, of course it's odd. However, my comment wasn't saying it's related with, merely that you should **"start with..."** and troubleshoot from there.

Comment: The description seems like a desktop crash more than some kind of logout. Are there .crash files in /var/crash that correspond to the times of these events? What about error messages in /var/log/syslog that correspond to the same times?

Comment: Note that I'm not saying this is a problem or a crash. It only happens when I press "delete" without logging in with my password after a restart. After logging in, everything is back to normal. To be very clear: I'm asking a question, not reporting a problem.